# What does BLU+ mean in a METAR?

Tags: metar

I know that `BLU` is military code and means "Ceiling at or above 2,500 feet; Visibility at or above 8,000 meters".

`ETSH 241320Z 19007KT 9999 SCT048 SCT160 BKN200 08/03 Q1008 BLU+`

`ETSH 241220Z 20005KT 9999 FEW050 SCT160 BKN240 08/03 Q1009 BLU+`

But what does `+` at the end signify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [German Meteorological Service](https://www.dwd.de/EN/specialusers/aviation/download/products/abkuerzungsverzeichnis_luftfahrt/abkuerzungsverzeichnis_luftfahrt.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2), the + means a ceiling 20,000 feet or higher.

> BLU: visibility>=8000m, ceiling 2500 - <20000 ft
>
> BLU+: visibility>=8000m, ceiling >=20000 ft